# CMake FetchContent show download progress

Tags: cmake

Is there some way to show download progress while downloading git repository using FetchContent?

I tried to clear `FETCHCONTENT_QUIET`, but it did nothing. I have no idea if it is even possible.

Comment: Can you please specify what platform/generator you are using?

Comment: I am using Windows/ninja, could it be dependent on platform?

Comment: It may be dependent on platform, but I know it's dependent on your generator. For Ninja, you need to set `USES_TERMINAL_DOWNLOAD` to `TRUE` in your call to `FetchContent_Declare()`.

Comment: Also, see CMake maintainer Craig Scott's explanation on this CMake [issues](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18238#note_440475) page.

Answer (score 20):

Clarification: To see `git clone` progress, you need to set both `FetchContent_Quiet` **and** `GIT_PROGRESS` as in the below example

```
Set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET FALSE)

FetchContent_Declare(
  someTarget
  GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/someone/someTarget.git"
  GIT_TAG "tag"
  GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)
```

Comment: GIT PROGRESS did not result in what I was looking for but FETCHCONTENT_QUIET did.

Answer (score 4):

I just figured out that I have to use `GIT_PROGRESS <bool>` in `FetchContent_Declare`.

```
FetchContent_Declare(
  someTarget
  GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/someone/someTarget.git"
  GIT_TAG "tag"
  GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)
```